# How to demonstrate that the main character of your story is narrating a story to other people in a scene?

Tags: creative-writing, structure, narrative, essay

Being new to writing narratives, I have a query in mind. In one particular scene, I want to show that my main character is narrating a story to the crowd. How can I accomplish this?

I am unable to ensure a smooth flow because it seems eerie that  a character is narrating another story in a narrative. I will be glad if anyone could help resolve my issue.

Comment: Are you planning to tell the story uninterrupted (in one long monologue), or would audience reactions or the narrator's thoughts be an option?

Comment: @Llewellyn I am planning to include audience reactions and continue the narrative with other explanations.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly you're struggling with? I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'it seems eerie' in this context

Comment: If veryVerde's answer helps you, please consider accepting it by clicking the green check mark next to it. On Stack Exchange, "closed" means a question does not meet the site's guidelines, which is not the case for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the time for the characters to talk about your character narrating the story. This gives the reader time to prepare for bigger narration. You can also try and mention this earlier on, which tells the reader that this large narration within a narration is coming.

Another method might also be your character doing preparatory things, such as filling up his drink, adjusting his seating, standing, taking in a deep breath, etc. I might even use both.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your contribution has absolutely helped me fix my narrative.

Comment: @vanillasucceeds Please note that you can press the checkmark next to veryVerde's answer to show that your problem was solved and the answer was the most helpful. Doing this also helps boost veryVerde's reputation and it gives you a +2 reputation bonus.